# Remove the commas, spaces and "NULL" string to 0(Zero) from Column

Tags: excel, vba

I am newbie to Excel VBA.

Need help to removing the commas, spaces and NULL string to "0" from ColumnName called StringName.

First, I have tried to remove the commas, spaces from the ColumnName called StringName and finally to find and replace the "NULL" string to 0(Zero).

Here is the code to Replace for commas, spaces from the ColumnName called StringName.

```
Sub ReplaceCharacters()

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim lrow As Long
    lrow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  With ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & lrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Cells
      .Replace What:=",", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
      .Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
  End With

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I am struggling to find and Replace the string "NULL" to 0 from the ColumnName called StringName.

I need help with this and I have tried a lot and ended up here for a solution.

Here is what I have tried..

```
' not working
Sub UpdateWhole()
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    .Replace "NULL", "0", xlWhole
    End With
End Sub

' not working
Sub FormulaRng()
    For i = 2 To 10
       Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(A" & i & "=""NULL"",0,A" & i & ")"
    Next
End Sub
```

Thanks in Advance

[image: screenshot]

Here is the sample data to test

```
StringName
------------------
NULL
NULL  
null 
nullasdf
cbgrgNULLdf343
, asdfwe 4fdt
456fg , d55nullNULL
sdf34      df,    4fd   
NULLfgf  null
121
22
34545

Required OutPut
------------------------
0
0
0
nullasdf
cbgrgNULLdf343
asdfwe4fdt
456fgd55nullNULL
sdf34df4fd
NULLfgfnull
121
22
34545
```

Comment: Is it possible your NULL cells have leading/trailing spaces or other invisible characters?

Comment: @ Tim Williams..   Thanks for quick response.. having spaces  and not having any special characters

Comment: Are you saying there *are*spaces?

Comment: i mean the space like "      NULL      "  and also the StringName having the # , _ and @ symbols... i want mainly to remove the  commas, spaces and finally  "NULL" string to 0(Zero)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following revised procedure should work for you. I used the [Clean](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/clean-function-26f3d7c5-475f-4a9c-90e5-4b8ba987ba41) function to remove all non-printable characters from the text before replacing the `NULL` text with `0`.

#### VBA Code

```
Public Sub ReplaceCharacters()
On Error GoTo ErrTrap
Const ProcedureName As String = "ReplaceCharacters"
Dim sheet           As Worksheet: Set sheet = ActiveSheet
Dim cell            As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each cell In sheet.UsedRange.Cells
        cell = Trim(Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(cell))
        cell.Replace What:="NULL", Replacement:=0, LookAt:=xlWhole
        cell.Replace What:=",", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
        cell.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
    Next cell

ExitProcedure:
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set sheet = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrTrap:
    Select Case Err.number
        Case Else
            Debug.Print "Procedure: " & ProcedureName & " |Error #: " & Err.number & " |Error Description: " & Err.description
    End Select
    Resume ExitProcedure
    Resume 'for debugging

End Sub
```

#### Example Video

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngDB As Range

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    With Ws
        Set rngDB = .Range("a2", .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
    With rngDB
        .Replace What:=",", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
        .Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
        .Replace What:="NULL", Replacement:="0", LookAt:=xlWhole
        .Replace What:="null", Replacement:="0", LookAt:=xlWhole
    End With


End Sub
```